# PHP not echoing Ż correctly

Tags: php

I have a problem with PHP. It's not printing out name of a folder I've grabbed with `readdir()` properly.
The problem is only with a single character that is used in Polish.

```
<?php
//var with directory, put in the directory containing albums here
$main = "C:/Users/Jakub/Desktop/devving/gallery/images/";
$counter = 0;
$albumdata = [];
//gets all albums inside of the folder and stores inside of an array
if($opendir = opendir($main)){
    while(($file = readdir($opendir)) !== false){
        if($file == "." or $file == "..")continue;
        $albumdata[$counter] = $file;
        $counter += 1;
    }
    closedir($opendir);
    $counter = 0;
}
//gets all files inside of albums and stores them inside of arrays with the names of the albums
for($i = 0;$i < count($albumdata); $i++){
    if($opendir = opendir($main . $albumdata[$i])){
        while(($file = readdir($opendir)) !== false){
            if($file == "." or $file == "..") continue;
            ${$albumdata[$i]}[$counter] = $file;
            $counter +=1;
        }
        closedir($opendir);
        $counter = 0;
    }
}
//echoes albums
for($i = 0;$i < count($albumdata); $i++){
    $counter += 1;
    if($counter == 1){
        echo "<div class = 'firstimg'><a href = '"."images/".$albumdata[$i]."'><img src = '"."images/".$albumdata[$i]."/".${$albumdata[$i]}[0]."'><p>".$albumdata[$i]."</p></a></div>";
    }else if($counter == 2){
        echo "<div class = 'secondimg'><a href = '"."images/".$albumdata[$i]."'><img src = '"."images/".$albumdata[$i]."/".${$albumdata[$i]}[0]."'><p>".$albumdata[$i]."</p></a></div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class = 'lastimg'><a href = '"."images/".$albumdata[$i]."'><img src = '"."images/".$albumdata[$i]."/".${$albumdata[$i]}[0]."'><p>".$albumdata[$i]."</p></a></div>";
        $counter = 0;
    }
}
```

?>

Here's the code. The albums in the $main directory are called `Koty`, `Krajobrazy`
`Ptaki` and `Żaby`. The problem is with the last one, instead of echoing `Żaby` in the paragraph
and the source it echoes `�aby`.
edit: Forgot to mention, I can echo Ż alone.

Comment: You probably have an encoding issue. Try manually sending the content type `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')`.

Comment: Where to do that and how?

Comment: Put `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` before echoing your html

Comment: That didn't really help

Comment: Also add it in your html: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: try adding mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); and header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); before html output

Comment: try `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`